1970's Film - People Plug Cords Into Their Necks
I'm looking for a 1970's futuristic sci-fi film. I recall, slightly, a scene where a person, sitting at desk, plugs a cord into their own neck. I think the “plug” is a guitar patch cord type of plug. There was more than one person plugin in; I do not know why they cords were plugged into necks. My mother, who also saw the film, says the people worked for, or pretended to be working for, the Phone Company. Clearly a sci-fi movie. The film is definitely pre-1975, so it is not Matrix, Mindwarp, eXistenZ, or Invaders from Mars (1953).
It is not a TV series, it is a full length film; could possibly be a Made-For-TV movie but I do not think it is. I saw this movie on network TV, in the evening, from Seattle, WA area between 1969-1973. I believe the movie was new at the time I saw it. I think it is either American or British made. It was not animated. Language is English.

Do you remember anything more about the people who either had the cords plugged into them, or the people who performed the plugins? Do you recall anything about the motivations (was it a fun source of entertainment, a sinister way of enslaving humanity, a neutral part of everyday society, whatever)? Also, what language was it in and was it a theatrical movie or a made for TV movie?

Was it a scifi flick? A couple movies come to mind; Saturn 3 and any of the Circuitry man movies.. Look em up; lemme know if those were it..

Not Saturn 3 (which is a great film). The film in question pre-dates Saturn 3 by about a decade.
